# Turn variable elements into string for json

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

How can I make a foreach in here to turn every $values_x array element into a string?

```
$values_x = '';
if ( isset( $chart_render_data['options']['xAxis']['categories'] ) ) {
    $values_x = $chart_render_data['options']['xAxis']['categories'];
}
```

$values_x outputs this, in the current graph I have:

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>float(2002)
  [1]=>float(2003)
  [2]=>float(2004)
  [3]=>float(2005)
  [4]=>float(2006)
  [5]=>float(2007)
  [6]=>float(2008)
  [7]=>float(2009)
  [8]=>float(2010)
  [9]=>float(2011)
  [10]=>float(2012)
  [11]=>float(2013)
  [12]=>float(2014)
  [13]=>float(2015)
}
bool(true)
```

And I need it to output "2002", etc.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try typecasting: (string) $series[0]['data'][$i][0];

Comment: that dosnt work, still comes as integers

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast a value to a string by appending the value to a empty string `$value = "".$value` or use the cast `(string)`

in your case

```
$yourArray['values'] = array_map($yourArray['values'], function($value) {return (string)$value;})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version with the exact same logic - wrap each value in quotes.  When you declare `$values_x` access each element (either via `array_map` or `foreach()`) and **wrap them with double quotes**.  As stated in another answer, casting as `(string)` will also work.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/26e5293e2ad6de4fd69eaa01210d93ab85ae5abc))

```
$chart_render_data['options']['xAxis']['categories']=array(
    array(2002),array(2003),array(2004),array(2005),array(2006),array(2007),
    array(2008),array(2009),array(2010),array(2011),array(2012),array(2013),
    array(2014),array(2015));

if(isset( $chart_render_data['options']['xAxis']['categories'])){
    $values_x=array_map(function($v){return "$v";},array_column($chart_render_data['options']['xAxis']['categories'],0));
}
foreach($values_x as $v){
    echo "$v is a ",gettype($v),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2002 is a string
2003 is a string
2004 is a string
2005 is a string
2006 is a string
2007 is a string
2008 is a string
2009 is a string
2010 is a string
2011 is a string
2012 is a string
2013 is a string
2014 is a string
2015 is a string
```

Comment: @phpqs Welcome to SO.  If my answer satisfies, please award it the green tick.  If not, please leave me a comment that says what isn't quite right.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, but it didnt worked mate. maybe if i turn $value_x to a string here `$values_x = '';
    if ( isset( $chart_render_data['options']['xAxis']['categories'] ) ) {
     $values_x = $chart_render_data['options']['xAxis']['categories'];
    } `
but with strval i got no luck

Comment: Well, it does work, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5007fbcf5a54ec420cd818c0eccd2ba3e7f8718c , but I'll keep chasing your edits until you are successful.

Comment: @phpqs Here is another version of the same answer based on your latest edit.  I've now gone to quite a length to explain a very simple process.  I hope this answer gains your approval.